# How to get the first non-NULL value in SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite, null

I have three columns of data. One column has ID and the second column has a date and the third column has BMI value. I want to create a fourth column that has the first_value based on date(ascending order) from the third column which is not null or avoiding the null.

So far, I have tried first_value in plain form which didn't work. I tried subsetting first_value inside the case when statement as

```
CASE 
  WHEN BMI IS NOT NULL THEN (FIRST_VALUE(BMI) OVER PARTITION BY PID ORDER BY DATE)) 
  ELSE 0 
END AS FIRSTNOTNULLVALUE_BMI
```

gave me 0s.

```
id    date         BMI 
1   2000-01-01    NULL
1   2003-05-01    18.1
1   2002-07-15    25.8
2   2009-09-25    NULL
2   2015-04-18    23.5
```

Any suggestions??

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, sql-server, postgresql...?

Comment: posted a sample data and added tags for databases.

Comment: Your sample data do not contain any nulls in BMI. Post sample data with null and **expected results**.

Comment: Also Mysql is not the same as SQLite. Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: You forgot the expected results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put that `CASE` in the `ORDER BY` of the `FIRST_VALUE`.
Then the null's will be sorted last for that function.

> ```
> create table test
> (
>   pid int,
>   pdate date,
>   BMI decimal(4,1)
> )
>
> insert into test (pid, pdate, BMI) values
>   (1, '2000-01-01', NULL)
> , (1, '2003-05-01', 18.5)
> , (1, '2002-07-15', 24.9)
> , (2, '2009-09-25', NULL)
> , (2, '2015-04-18', 21.7)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> select *
> , first_value(BMI) over (partition by pid order by case when BMI is not null then 1 else 2 end, date(pdate)) as firstBMI
> from test
> order by pid, pdate
> ```
>
> ```
> pid | pdate      | BMI  | firstBMI
> :-- | :--------- | :--- | :-------
> 1   | 2000-01-01 | null | 24.9    
> 1   | 2002-07-15 | 24.9 | 24.9    
> 1   | 2003-05-01 | 18.5 | 24.9    
> 2   | 2009-09-25 | null | 21.7    
> 2   | 2015-04-18 | 21.7 | 21.7
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=7947ed521c3e2e6c4a3cf91e189a4894)*

Comment: Thank you so much! You guided me to right direction. I edited the above code as select *, first_value(bmi) over(partition by pid order by case when bmi is null then 1 else 0 end) as firstnonnull_bmi
from vitals_f2 order by pid;

Comment: @PrajwalManiPradhan Thx, I corrected the answer.  Btw, only an order by the `CASE` isn't enough to get the oldest non-null BMI

Answer (score 1):

You could join your table with a subquery that recovers the first non-null BMI, date-wise:

```
select
    t.*,
    x.bmi first_non_null_bmi
from mytable t
cross join (select bmi from mytable where bmi is not null order by date limit 1) x
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this.. maybe will work.. or gives you any idea

```
   THEN (select BIM = row_number() over (partition by BIM order by DATE desc/asc) 
      from Products)
ELSE..
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a subquery:

```
select bmi.*,
       (select bmi2.bmi
        from bmi bmi2
        where bmi2.id = bmi.id and bmi2.bmi is not null
        order by bmi2.date
        limit 1
       ) as first_bmi
from bmi;
```